# Setting Windows server as NTP server but keeping client settings untouched

Tags: window, ntp

I'm working on an installation module (C#) for a distributed system.
One of the requirements is being able to setup one of the servers as an NTP server (windows time service).
I've followed several MS articles, for example:[this one](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816042#method2)
but it seems that each one also requires to configure the NTP client settings (for example changing the server type from Nt5DS to NTP).

Any idea of how to keep a server's existing NTP client settings untouched while setting it as NTP server?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

After investigating this issue for a while, looks like that's impossible.
After reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/cc773263%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) post, I understand that the same registry key is used for both NTP client and server protocols, meaning, if the same machine needs to be a client and a serve but the client should work with, let's say, NT5DS and the server's protocol is obviously NTP than it can't work.